# Counting number of ways to place bags and marbles inside bags so all bags contain an odd number of marbles

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

There was a famous trick question posed once in math.stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/555024/33907). The question can be loosely translated to "Is it possible to place nine marbles into four bags so that each bag  has an odd amount of marbles?"

If we don't allow for bags to be inside bags this is clearly impossible. However putting all of the marbles into a bag and the putting each bag inside another bag gives us a possible solution. I would like to know how many ways there are to so this for an arbitrary number of bags $k$ and an arbitrary number of marbles $n$. Of course the problem is ambiguous. So I have tried to formalize it as follows:

---

Consider the set $[n]$ and a positive integer $k$. Now consider the set $F$ of  multisets $M$ of subsets of $[n]$  such that:

- There are exactly $k$ elements in $M$
- Subsets can appear more than once in $M$ ( So for example $M$ can contain the same subset twice)
- Each subset $A$ in $M$ has an odd number of elements
- Two intersecting subsets $A$ and $B$ in $M$ satisfy $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$
- Every element of $[n]$ belongs to at least one of the subsets in $M$.

We call two multisets $M$ and $N$ of $F$ isomorphic if there is a bijection $\sigma$ of $[n]$ such that every subset $s$ of $[n]$ appears with the same multiplicity in $M$ as $\sigma(s)$ in $N$.

How many different isomorphism types does $F$ have? Call this number $f(n,k)$

Comment: In the m.se question, you want each bag to have an *odd* number of marbles. *Even* is impossible, bags inside bags or not.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I made a mistake in the first paragraph.

Comment: I am thinking another way to rephrase the problem is as follows: Given the set $B=\{1,2,3\dots k\}$ of bags give a partial order to the set and a function $f$ from $B$ to $\mathbb N$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k f(i)=n$ and for each $b$ we have $\sum\limits_{d\leq b} f(d)$ is odd. Where here the partial order would be bag containment $(a\leq b$ if bag $a$ is contained in bag $b$ or $a=b$ ).

Comment: I would suggest calculating $f(n,k)$ for various small values of the variables, looking for patterns, consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, etc.

Comment: This is equivalent to counting isomorphism types of certain bipartite graphs defined by nontrivial properties. If there is an exact formula at all, it will some messy summation out of Polya's Theorem. Asymptotics might be possible, but not easily.

Comment: Wow Brendan, that sounds very interesting. Thank you very much. I would very much like to know about those bipartite graphs and the properties.

Comment: I don't see why it makes sense to use an arbitrary partial order on bags. Suppose $A$ is contained in $B$ and $C$, but $B$ and $C$ are incomparable. How would this look, physically? If this is possible, then let $A$ vanish, and whatever marble was in $A$ is in $B$ and $C$ even though they are incomparable. So, what stops us from saying that marbles get to be in arbitrary subsets of bags if the bags are incomparable? You can, if you want, pose this as a problem, but it doesn't seem to model the situation with physical bags.

Comment: You might say that instead of allowing arbitrary partial orders, you have a rooted forest. My guess is that you would get some nice enumerations that way.

Comment: Yes @DouglasZare you are right. I made a mistake when trying to rephrase the problem. It should be a partial order such that if $a\leq b$ and $a\leq c$ then $b\leq c$ or $c\leq b$. Although we should probably only work with such partial orders up to isomorphism type.